# Linking CSS PHP and Images without using absolute or relative URLs

Tags: php, html, css

How do I though code, create a system for urls to other php files, which avoids the issue that can result in moving files.

Comment: Links can be relative or absolute, there is no other option

Comment: Don't ask a question twice. Improve your question or earn reputation and offer a bounty, that's the way to go here. Besides, that's a horrible blob of text to anyone reading this. Format it better and [add some code with what you've tried so far](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: @Gerald Schneider it would end up being absolute, but the root would be stored in one place. I couldn't get that to work so I was wondering what is the correct way to go about this.

Comment: Your question is much elaborative than needed, still no clue to what you have done yet. Ask in an informative way to make it clear.

Comment: work it out with the people you're working with on a folder structure... or you're just going to spend time changing each other's folder structure everytime you're working on the project and it's just going to be a waste of everyone's time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, please note that this architecture is deeply flawed and you should explain your needs better so we can help you find another way to solve this. Also, there is nothing other that relative or absolute url, what you are asking is not a magical third way, but only "how to figure out what my absolute path is no matter how deep I am".

If you decide to keep with this, you can use an environment variable in your virtual host

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    #...
    SetEnv URL_ROOT "/foo/bar/42"
</VirtualHost>
```

You can then read it from php without needing to read any relative path / knowing where the file is:

```
<?php
$url_root = getenv('URL_ROOT');
define('URL_ROOT', $url_root == false ? '/' : $url_root);
```

An alternative solution would be to use [auto_prepend_file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) in your php.ini

Answer (score 1):

URL are absolute or relative, nothing else but in your case, you can use a routing system, look at the Symfony routing component, it can gives you ideas http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/routing/introduction.html